# Coordinates of intersection between Ray and Plane

Tags: three.js

I have got a ray and a plane. The ray is intersecting the plane and I would like to know where. How do I get the world-coordinates of this intersetion?

(My particular case I unproject screen-coordinates to the camera and create the ray. The plane is the ground of the scene)

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 1 );
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
var ray = new THREE.Ray(
    camera.position,
    vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize()
);
```

Comment: In the recent README for THREE .. "* Renamed `Vector*/Matrix*/Quaternion`'s `addSelf()/subSelf()/crossSelf()...` to `add()/sub()/cross()...`."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the usual pattern. You may have to adapt it to fit your particular situation.

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once and reuse
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once and reuse

...

mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursiveFlag );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    console.log( intersects[ 0 ].point; );

}
```

Here, `objects` is an array. For example,

```
var objects = [];

objects.push( plane_mesh );
```

EDIT: Updated for three.js r.84

Comment: Oh there is an attribute called 'point'. Thats easy.. thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for updating it for r58. I am attempting to get the location on a plane (new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 400, 10, 10)) with using the worldToLocal function, but the coordinates seem to be screwing up, the X seems to have the right range (-200 to 200), but the Y seems to be a little short one it. Is this normally how it would be done?

Comment: @drakej You'll have to post a new question. Be sure to include your code.

Comment: add whats recursiveFlag?

Answer (score 1):

As of r55, you can use this shortcut. It's similar, but simplifies raycasting to the point where you don't even have to worry about unprojectVector().

Here's a modified version of WestLangley's example:

```
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( 
        event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
        - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 
        0.5 
    );

    var ray = projector.pickingRay( vector.clone(), camera );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        console.log( intersects[ 0 ].point; );

    }
```

This assumes the same objects array

```
var objects = [];

objects.push( plane_mesh );
```