# Find the coordinates of the topleft of the canvas on the xy plane given a camera

Tags: three.js

I think this is an ok way to get the xyplane (if this is wrong or there is a better way, let me know):

```
    xyplane = new THREE.Plane().setFromCoplanarPoints(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(10, 15, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(100, -90, 0),
    );
```

I have a camera which happens to be at `(0, 0, 1000)` looking at the origin. I can find a coordinate that is the exact top left of my viewing port:

```
    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    topleft = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0);
    through = projector.unprojectVector(topleft, camera);
```

`through` is then `THREE.Vector3 {x: -31.425217496422327, y: 22.169468302342334, z: 900.0000201165681}` which is perfectly at the topleft of the canvas. However, I want to find the equivalent point where z = 0. I try to do this with a ray; but, I fail.

```
    ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, through);
    point = ray.intersectPlane(xyplane);
```

`point` is then `{x: 34.91690754890442, y: -24.632742007573448, z: 0}` which is not even close. I'm misunderstanding something basic. I will study [Coordinates of intersection between Ray and Plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748677/coordinates-of-intersection-between-ray-and-plane) and others while I try to figure this out. Maybe someone can explain in plain language.

Comment: You are almost there. The second argument to `THREE.Ray()` must be a direction vector of unit length that points from the camera toward your target point.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, your comment made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Right, thanks to @WestLangley for the comment. The `through` variable is not the correct second argument to the `Ray` constructor. We need a unit vector for direction. With the camera position and the `through` point, we can get a direction vector with:

```
    direction = through.sub(camera.position).normalize();
```

Then the rest works as expected:

```
    ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, direction);
    p = ray.intersectPlane(xyplane);
```